# Twilio. Redirect incoming call to another worker

Tags: twilio

Now I am testing Twilio calls and there is one issue, which I cannot solve:
I have 2 pages in my app for 2 workers - "joey" and "dima". Incoming calls connect to "joey" and I can handle these calls from "joey page".
My question is: can I redirect accepted incoming calls to another worker to handle this call from  another page (in this example from "dima" page)?

Comment: what are you using Twilio voice calls? or Twilio Task router? There can be different ways for both.

Comment: @BilalMehrban To create web pages I used this article [link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/tutorials/incoming-calls).  
But I also use TaskRouter and my Twilio number has webhook for incoming calls to create new tasks as it is described here [link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/quickstart/php/twiml-receive-call).
And my workflow in TaskRouter has 'assignment callback url' like in this article: [link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/quickstart/php/twiml-dequeue-call) but with 'to' = 'client:joey'  instead of number

Comment: In case of task router do you want to like have a option using which one worker can transfer call to other?

Comment: I want that one manager will be able to redirect incoming to call to another manager. In my example, I want "joey" after accepting incoming call can redirect this call to "dima" from his web page. And manager "dima" can accept this call from his web page.

Comment: here is a perfect example for your use case. https://github.com/vernig/twilio-taskrouter-agent-frontend

Comment: @BilalMehrban, yes, it solved my issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: I am posting this as answer, accept it as answer and upvote as well.

Comment: You are welcome! @Andrew accept the answer and upvote it also. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the use case mentioned in the question the best solution that I come across was in GitHub repo [Here](https://github.com/vernig/twilio-taskrouter-agent-frontend).